# Javascript for loop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to click on any div from an array and have the box change it's opacity. I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spencerlarry/mfgpehzp/) to explain better what I mean. I have the code working with plain javascript but I don't know how to do the same with jquery. Thanks for your help!

```
$('.mind:eq(i)').click(function () {
    $('.mind:eq(i)').css('opacity', '1');
});

//Plain javascript
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
function change(i2) {
    box[i2].onclick = function () {
        box[i2].style.opacity = "1";
    };
}
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    change(i);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the `for loop` or just have a general function that changes the opacity on click?

Comment: Just a general function that changes the opacity on click. That's the only way I knew how by using plain javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **this** for current selected element

```
$('.box').click(function () {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfgpehzp/1/)**

Comment: Wow. I had no idea it would be that simple. Thanks!